# How to avoid specifying type parameters

Tags: c#, generics

I have this extension method:

```
    public static void PublishOnClient<THub, T>(this IObservable<T> observable, Expression<Func<THub, dynamic>> expression) where THub : Hub, new ()
    {
        var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExpression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("'expression' should be a member expression");
        }

        observable.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(memberExpression.Member.Name));
    }
```

I use it like that:

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
          .PublishOnClient<TicketHub, long>(x => x.SomeValue);
```

But I would rather like to use it without specifying T like that:

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
          .PublishOnClient<TicketHub>(x => x.SomeValue);
```

I don't care about T at all. All I want is to provide THub to have a type safe way to get the string of a member property. However I want the extension method to be available on IObservable. How could I do this?

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2010/12/partial-type-inference-in-net.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* you can get away with introducing an intermediate type, like this:

```
// All these names are bad... I don't know the domain here :)
public class Publisher<T>
{
    private readonly IObservable<T> observable;

    internal Publisher(IObservable<T> observable)
    {
        this.observable = observable;
    }

    public void OnClient<THub>(Expression<Func<THub, dynamic>> expression)
    {
        var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExpression == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(...);
        }

        string name = memberExpression.Member.Name;
        observable.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(name));
    }
}

public static class ObservableExtensions
{
    public static Publisher<T> Publish<T>(this IObservable<T> observable)
    {
        return new Publisher<T>(observable);
    }
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
          .Publish().OnClient<TicketHub>(x => x.SomeValue);
```

The `Publish()` method uses type inference for `T`, leaving just *one* type parameter to supply for the `OnClient()` method.

It means you have to make two method calls rather than one, but that's the price you pay for wanting "partial" type inference :(

Comment: Thats crazy delicous and makes the usage so much simpler. There is just one little mistake in your code. In your publish method you must change the return type to Publisher<T> ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You must either specify all parameters explicitly or have all of them be implicitly decided by the args. C# does not support partial parameter specification.

Comment: That's true, but it seems like an inordinate amount of work to avoid adding a type parameter.

Comment: It depends on how much it's going to be used. It often makes sense to put a bit more effort into making something smooth in order to clean up the rest of the codebase.

Comment: Agreed - I guess now that I think about it, anytime I've written a "partially-inferenced" method, I ended up rewriting it because it became a much-better engineered solution.